# Objective-C selector deprecated replacement

Tags: ios, swift

As many question have shown recently, literal selectors are deprecated. There's a quick fix, which works fine if selector is just in that one class.

But consider this example (I have a lot more code; this is a simplified example):

```
static func createMenuButton(controller:UIViewController) -> UIBarButtonItem {
    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22))
    menuButton.addTarget(controller, action: Selector("menuButtonClicked:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    let menuButtonContainer = UIView(frame: menuButton.frame)
    menuButtonContainer.addSubview(menuButton)
    let menuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButtonContainer)
    return menuButtonItem
}
```

This utility method gives me good functionality to be used in various view controllers. Because of its multiple usage, I'd have to copy it to each view controller to use the new `#selector` syntax. But Apple, why deprecate more dynamic method? I guess in new release they'll just remove it, like `i++`, `i--` and C-style `for` loops (but they can be easily replaced, though I don't get why they remove them). Are there any workarounds to keep this approach working in future releases? Each new release breaks all my projects syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why deprecate more dynamic method?

From [the proposal to make this change](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md):

> we free the developer from having to do the naming translation manually and get static checking that the method exists and is exposed to Objective-C.

For your approach, you could make a protocol that indicates a certain method is present:

```
@objc protocol MenuButtonClickable {
    func menuButtonClicked()
}
```

In your view controller, add this method:

```
extension MyViewController : MenuButtonClickable {
    func menuButtonClicked() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then update your method signature to use this protocol:

```
static func createMenuButton(controller:MenuButtonClickable) -> UIBarButtonItem {
```

Now the Swift compiler is guaranteed that `controller` has that method, so you'll be able to use the new `#selector` syntax.

And if you accidentally try to use this method on a view controller without this function, you'll get a compile-time error instead of a runtime error.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Your protocol method is working. What's strange that I didn't have to write an extension to existing classes and it still worked.. As for deprecating some methods I've already read that and still don't agree.. Removing syntax will break a lot of code. I can fix my code, but that takes time.. And also I use a lot of 3rd party libraries..

Comment: @Makalele I'm happy it worked! The `extension` isn't required, it's just a style suggestion to keep your protocol implementations separate from each other. I suspect Swift code will continue to break semi-regularly for the next few years, so if it's really annoying you, you might want to go back to Objective-C.

Comment: Yeah I know extension isn't required, but I though I have to at least conform that protocol in all classes that are using it. Instead I didn't have to do anything and it worked. Changing "menuButtonClicked" for "menuButtonClicked2" didn't raise any errors at compilation time. But of course app crashed, when I tried to trigger it. What exactly @objc keyword gives in that code?

Comment: `@objc` means for a type to conform to that protocol, it must be convertible to an Objective-C type (ie, it can't be a Swift struct). If you remove the `@objc` the `addTarget:` line won't compile because a `MenuButtonClickable` won't be convertible to `id`.