# Notification center crash in swift 3

Tags: swift3

I shifted to swift3 a little while ago. Even after converting to swift3, the notification center code below was working fine (no crashes and doing what it was supposed to).

I was experimenting with force touch in some other parts of the code when suddenly the app started crashing (SIGBRT...'unrecognized selector' sent).

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("applicationWillEnterBackGround:")), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
```

Cleaned the build, ran it again. Not sure what might be causing this ? Still pretty new to Swift, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the capital G in `Selector(("applicationWillEnterBackGround:"))`.

But why on earth are you even writing code like this? Use `#selector` syntax; its whole purpose is to prevent this sort of silliness.

Also, you never being doing anything to *call* `applicationWillEndBackground`. That is something only the runtime calls. You have no right to configure a notification like this.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I switched to #selector syntax and it works fine. I actually understand how it's working now!. Thanks for the hint. I am not doing anything with the application entering background - that was just for example/debug. I am doing some stuff when the app enters foreground.

Comment: @karthiksarpatwari see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36211714/5175709)